# Dynamic field (array input) validation with error message with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have two input field in my form: the number of children and children name where children name field will be dynamically generated after getting user input in a children_number field.
I can validate the children_number field. But I am facing difficulties to validate children name field with error message.

My main purpose is display error message. Here I am trying with Js client-side validation.

```
// Validate children number

function validateNumber_children(x){
    var re = /[1-9]$/;
    if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#ccffcc';
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#F6CECE';
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
}

// Validate childrens name

function validateStudent_name(x){
    var arr = document.getElementsById('student_name[]');
    var re = /[a-z]$/;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
       if  ((arr[i].value)= '') {
           return false;
       }
    if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#ccffcc';
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#F6CECE';
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false;

       }
    }
}


function validateForm() {
    // Set error variable
    var error = 0;
    // For number of children
    if (!validateNumber_children('number_children')) {
        document.getElementById('number_childrenError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
    }

   // for children name

    if(!validateStudent_name('children_name')){
       document.getElementById('student_nameError').style.display = "block";
       error++;
}

if(error > 0){
    return false;
}
}
```

My html form

```
<form method="POST" action="/contact-us" autocomplete="off" id="test"  onsubmit="return validateForm()">

    <div class="form-group fieldGroup">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Number of Children </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number_children" id = "number_children" placeholder="Enter number of children" onblur="validateNumber_children(number_children)"  value="{{ old('number_children') }}" >
                <span id="number_childrenError" style="display: none;">You must enter a integer  number. Ex: 4 </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <div id="outputArea">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Reset">
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Java Script code

```
$("#number_children").change(function() {
    var htmlString = "";
    var len = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        k = i+1;
        "<br>"
        htmlString += (' \Children Information '+ k +')  ;
        htmlString +=

            "    <label> Name of Student </label>\n" +
            "    <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"student_name[]\" id=\"children_name[]\" onblur =\"validateStudent_name(student_name[])\" placeholder=\"Student Name"+ k +"\" value = \"{{ old('student_name.*') }}\">\n" +
            " <span id=\"student_nameError\" style=\"display: none;\"> You must enter children's name</span>"+
    }
    $("#outputArea").html(htmlString);
})
```

jQuery to trigger

```
$(function(){
    //jQuery code here
    $('#number_children').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Can you please post valid js code as the one you have provided will cause syntax errors

Comment: "“It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details”. I am having this issue when i wanted to update

Comment: Maybe put it as a snippet?

Comment: could you please indicate me which part showing the syntax error. I am  sure that javascript code for validate children_name will show error and I got stuck in this part.

Comment: you have lone "<br>" in the js code and matching quotation mark on first assignment to htmlString. But even after correcting this, there still is syntax error

Comment: htmlString +=
                "<div class=\"col-md-6\">"+
                "<div class=\"form-group\">\n" +
                "    <label> Name of Student </label>\n" +
                "    <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"student_name[]\" id=\"student_name[]\" onblur =\"validateStudent_name(student_name[])\" placeholder=\"Student Name"+ k +"\" value = \"{{ old('student_name.*') }}\">\n" +
                " <span id=\"children_nameError\" style=\"display: none;\"> You must enter children's name</span>"+
                "</div> "+
                "</div> "

Comment: You can remove "<br>". Actually, I have removed CSS part